# running an installation command in bash: "n" followed by "Y" without any manual intervention

Tags: sh, pacman-package-manager

So on a fresh instance of arch linux, I want to be able to install `tzdata` from the get-go.

To do so manually, I do this:-

```
[root@myarch ~]# pacman -S tzdata
:: The following packages should be upgraded first :
    pacman
:: Do you want to cancel the current operation
:: and upgrade these packages now? [Y/n] n

resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Targets (1): tzdata-2012c-1

Total Download Size:    0.13 MB
Total Installed Size:   5.41 MB

Proceed with installation? [Y/n] Y
```

As can be seen, I have to first key in `n`, followed by `Y`.

How do I run run this in one single line of bash without needing to key in `n` and `Y`?

```
yes n | pacman -S tzdata
```

gets me pass the first prompt. But I get stuck on the second prompt (obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{ echo n ; yes ; } | pacman ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send multiple inputs to a program like this, one way is to have multiple echo commands in a subshell:

```
(echo n; echo y) | pacman -S tzdata
```

Side note: Pacman really should be updated first if there's an update. Then you could just use `--noconfirm` like the other answer says.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
echo -e 'n\nY' | pacman -S tzdata
```

Comment: this isn't portable. better to use printf

Comment: How portable does it need to be? He is using the Arch package manager.

Comment: my comment was more for others who might mistakenly conclude that echo -e is correct to use for other things